# Python panda ammending specific column values based on length

Tags: python, pandas

I have a subset of a dataframe and within that subset I have a column titled 'Place_of_birth'.

If the place of birth ends with two character (ie; 'Pasadena, Ca') that is in the USA, so I need to update the data to include the country of birth wherever the data ends in two characters.

All other data within the column that is not USA based does not end/contain a word with two characters.

I need a function that can add the country of birth to the rows, but will not alter the data of non-US based locations.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

birth_data = {'place_of_birth': ['Pasadena, Ca','Glasgow, Scotland','Chicago, Il','Bisacquino, Sicily, Italy'],
        'year_of_birth': [1997, 1976, 1981, 1992]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(birth_data, columns = ['place_of_birth', 'year_of_birth'])

print (df)
```

The 'place_of_birth' column should then be:

Pasandena, Ca, USA

Glasgow, Scotland

etc...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do the non USA places have commas in them? If they don't then you could just check to see if the string has a comma and use that to determine if its in the US or not.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with sample input and expected output, as well as code for what you've tried so far so that we better understand how to help

Comment: Also, when someone provides this link ===> [mcve] You are meant to click it and read the contents and edit your question to make it easier for us to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Most have commas but not all, all USA places do I believe!
First time using SO apologies

Answer (score 0):

Accroding to the explanation you provide, if the Place_of_birth has strings seperated by comma and if the last word has two characters, then the country should be USA, you can use `np.select`

```
import numpy as np
df['Country'] = np.select([df['Place_of_birth'].str.split(',').str[-1].str.len()==2], ['USA'], None)
```

If you dont want  None, you can replace None with empty string i.e. ''

Comment: Tried and ended up with a new column filled with 'None' regardless of string length, also I think you mean ')' rather than ']' at the end